# Console.Title c# current time

Tags: c#, linq, console, title

I am making a tetris program in c# and i would like to represent the remaining time in the title of the console.

Why does this not compile?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Timers;

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();
            do
            {
                Console.Title("Elapsed time:" +  stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);`


            } while (true);
            stopwatch.Stop();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

> Error 1   Non-invocable member 'System.Console.Title' cannot be used like a method. C:\Users\Bence\Documents\C#\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8\Prog‌​ram.cs  19  25 ConsoleApplication8

Comment: "Why does it not working?" That doesn't tell us anything about what you're actually seeing. (As far as I can see, it shouldn't even compile, as `Console.Title` is a property, not a method.)

Comment: Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.Console.Title' cannot be used like a method. C:\Users\Bence\Documents\C#\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8\Program.cs 19 25 ConsoleApplication8

Comment: Your bigger problem will come in the fact that you won't ever be able to read a key

Comment: It doesn't build but i need to represent time somehow in the Title of the console.

Comment: I would like to do it as a thread

Comment: Code-snippets that don't compile should not be allowed on SO...

Comment: @DrKoch - sometimes the fact it won't compile is what people struggle with. Interpreting the compiler's output can sometimes require a bit of guidance itself for those new to it. So I couldn't disagree with you more.

Comment: @DeeMac fine. In these cases we talk about error messages from a compiler

Comment: @DrKoch - But you've just suggested we shouldn't!?

Comment: @HambalkóBence do you read and or understand your error that you are getting.. ? basically what it's telling you is that you are trying to assign the `Title` property by passing parameters`Console.Title("Elapsed time:" +  stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);' 'Title` does not take any parameters come on now.. here is a simple page that you should read and utilize until you become more proficient with .net programming
[C# Basics Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm)

Comment: @DeeMac ok, this was too angry and too fast. But illustrating a question unrelated to compiler messages with some code that does not compile is really bad...

Comment: @DrKoch Agree that the question was weak. I edited the compiler error into the question; now it should be clear.

Comment: The code will produce a 100% CPU usage. Add some Sleep() inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This is what i ended up with:


`public static void idothread()
            {
                var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();

               while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Console.Title = "TETRISZ:" + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " s";
                    
                   
                }
            }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, like the error message says, [`Console.Title`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.console.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx), but a [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), so have to use:

```
Console.Title = "Elapsed time:" +  stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```

You should read the compiler output more carefully. Also note that the code after the loop will never be reached (the compiler also tells you that), so your loop runs forever.

Some further notes:

- You can format numbers so the title would not look like `Elapsed time:1,3242346238`, see [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
  Example:

`Console.Title = String.Format("Elapsed time: {0:N}", stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);`

- You would probably have discovered it by yourself, but running such a tight loop will consume 100% CPU usage (DrKoch already told you this in a comment).
- Using the console for complex graphical output sucks. Why not use a game engine? (even WinForms would be better)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Is my answer somehow not helpful?

Answer (score -1):

You're in a while loop, not a tick event.

Also

```
Console.Title = "Elapsed time:" +  stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
```